# Ignore parts of URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a simple script to scrape the channel ID of a YouTube URL.

For example, to get the channel ID on this URL:

```
$url = 'https://youtube.com/channel/UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag';
```

I use regex:

```
preg_match( '/\/channel\/(([^\/])+?)$/', $url, $matches );
```

Works fine. But if the URL has any extra parameters or anything else after the channel ID, it doesn't work. Example:

```
https://youtube.com/channel/UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag?PARAMETER=HELLO
https://youtube.com/channel/UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag/RANDOMFOLDER
etc...
```

My question is, how can I adjust my regex so it works with *those* URLs? We don't want to match with the random parameters etc

Feel free to test my [ideone](https://ideone.com/SB03y2) code.

Comment: Try `'channel_id'  => '\/channel\/([^\/?#]+)'` and `'user'        =>  '\/user\/([^\/?#]+)'`. See https://ideone.com/dQLXg2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Dude, you are the regex legend on this platform. Thank you. Do you wanna post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Hint: when you share IDEONE links with URLs inside, please concat the URL strings or the site will "mask" them for all users but you and only during the "grace" period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the regexps in the following way:

```php
$preg_entities        = [
        'channel_id'  => '\/channel\/([^\/?#]+)', //match YouTube channel ID from url
        'user'        => '\/user\/([^\/?#]+)',    //match YouTube user from url
    ];
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/dQLXg2).

With `[^\/?#]+` patterns, the regex won't go through the query string in an URL, and you will get clear values in the output.

Full code snippet:

```php
function getYouTubeXMLUrl( $url) {
    $xml_youtube_url_base = 'h'.'ttps://youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml';
    $preg_entities        = [
        'channel_id'  => '\/channel\/([^\/?#]+)', //match YouTube channel ID from url
        'user'        => '\/user\/([^\/?#]+)',    //match YouTube user from url
    ];

    foreach ( $preg_entities as $key => $preg_entity ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/' . $preg_entity . '/', $url, $matches ) ) {
            if ( isset( $matches[1] ) ) {
                return [
                        'rss' => $xml_youtube_url_base . '?' . $key . '=' . $matches[1],
                        'id' => $matches[1],
                        'type' => $key,
                    ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```php
$url = 'https://youtube.com/channel/UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag?PARAMETER=HELLO';
print_r(getYouTubeXMLUrl($url));
// => Array( [rss] => https://youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag [id] => UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag [type] => channel_id )
$url = 'https://youtube.com/channel/UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag/RANDOMFOLDER';
print_r(getYouTubeXMLUrl($url));
// => Array( [rss] => https://youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag [id] => UCBLAoqCQyz6a0OvwXWzKZag [type] => channel_id )
```